# bash: loading presaved variable to gnuplot cmd load

Tags: bash, gnuplot

My intention is to have loaded variable `i` in for cycle - I want to have it usable for this cycle. Current state is that gnuplot loads var `i` from the first echo as a string not var.

```
SPEED=5

echo "plot '< head -n \"\$((SPEED*i))\" `echo ${INFILE}`' using 1:3 ;">> file.plt

for ((i=1;i<="$FRAMES";i++))                                     
do      
    echo  " 
        load '`echo ${file.plt}`';  
        " | gnuplot
done
```

Comment: Is using `echo` in `\`echo ${INFILE}\`` and `\`echo ${INFILE}\`` necessary? Why don't you just incorporate the variable by itself?

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for - `i` is your loop iteration variable. Is that the same as the `i` in the multiplication (`SPEED * i`)?

Comment: Yes, I want to replace `i` from multiplication by `i` value from loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can probably do all of this in gnuplot directly...

```
if(! exists("N")) N=0
FRAMES=10
FILE='myfile.plt'
SPEED=5
f(i)=sprintf("< head -n %d ".FILE,i+SPEED)
plot f(N) using 1:3
if(N < FRAMES) N=N+1
if(N < FRAMES) reread
```

---

Gnuplot 4.6 makes this even easier:

```
do for [N=1:10]{
   FILE='myfile.plt'
   SPEED=5
   f(i)=sprintf("< head -n %d ".FILE,i+SPEED)
   plot f(N) using 1:3
```

}

---

and instead of using `head`, you can probably use the `every` datafile modifier (`help every` for details).  I think something like the following:

```
NPT=N+SPEED
plot FILE every ::::NPT using 1:3
```

Comment: @shelter There's also plot iteration in gnuplot 4.3+, but I think that would have a different result (it would put all the plots on the same graph) as opposed to having each of the plots in their own graph.