# Gnuplot through bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnuplot

I need to generate a graphic gnuplot using a bash script because I have multiple file to plot.

```
while [ $j -lt 30 ]; 
  do
    if [ -f ./MyFile[$j] ]; then 
    load 'Plot_Histogramma.plt'
    fi
j=$(( $j + 1 ))
done
```

inside "Plot_Hisogramma.plt" i have

```
set output "MyFile[$j].eps"
plot "./MyFile[$j]" using 2:1 title "MyTitle" with boxes ls 7 lc rgb "blue"
```

So I need a method to pass my index variable from the script to the gnuplot. I tried with `echo`, `printf` and export but maybe, I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: It seems to me, that you want to see `MyFile[0].eps` etc. in "Plot_Hisogramma.plt".  Is this really a filename? Seems to me a bit unusual, I have a little impression that you may speak about a variable from bash, that would look like `${MyFile[0]}` in bash.  If this is not a case, forget it, just a comment...

Comment: That's normal. You can tell gnuplot to write to postscript, jpg, png, etc.. It is just setting the format for the output file (if other than the display)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be misreferring the array:

```
while [ $j -lt 30 ]; do
    if [ -f ./${MyFile[$j]} ]; then 
    load 'Plot_Histogramma.plt'
    fi
j=$(( $j + 1 ))
done
```

And then the other script which I believe should be like this:

```
set output "${MyFile[$j]}.eps"
plot "./${MyFile[$j]}" using 2:1 title "MyTitle" with boxes ls 7 lc rgb "blue"
```

Also maybe this link helps: [bash: loading presaved variable to gnuplot cmd load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10532168/bash-loading-presaved-variable-to-gnuplot-cmd-load)